# zf add fold marker comments with preceding spaces

Tags: folding, whitespace

Setting `foldmethod=marker`, I can highlight a few lines, press `zf` to fold them. By default vi will add `{{{` and `}}}` at the ends of the beginning and ending lines. I am working on shell scripts with filename.sh. I find that vim is clever enough to add `#{{{` and `#}}}` if that particular line is (ending with) code, which the preceding `#` is intended to comment out the curly brackets. However vi does not add a space before `#`, which makes this `#{{{` comment mess up with the code indeed.

The correct way would be adding  `#{{{` and  `#}}}`. `set foldmarker=\ #\ {{{,\ #\ }}}` does not work, as vi will add an extra `#` sign, without leading space, before the custom fold markers.

In fact, we do not need vi to be so smart to distinguish between codes or comments. Just blindly adding  `#{{{` and  `#}}}` (with preceding spaces) will work in both cases. This won't harm in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim uses the 'commentstring' option to start a comment if this option is not empty. The placeholder `%s` inside the 'commentstring' option is replaced with the opening and closing foldmarkers, respectively.

The default commentstring for shell scripts is `#%s`, so there is no leading space. You can change that with `set commentstring=\ #%s`. Because this option is currently only used to add markers for folding (see `:help 'commentstring'`) you should not notice unwanted side effects.

See `:help fold-create-marker` for the details.

Comment: Thank you @JürgenKrämer. I do not know why only `set commentstring=\ #%s` in `~/.vimrc` has no effect. With reference to [another post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28015/42115), wrap it inside `augroup` does the job perfectly. It turns out I am using `setlocal foldmarker=\ {{{,\ }}}`, `augroup MyCommentStringGroup` \n
`autocmd FileType sh setlocal commentstring=\ #%s` \n
`augroup END` which gives me very nice `zf` markups.

Comment: @midnite You can check where this option was last set with `:verbose set commentstring?`. I would guess it is set by the standard sh filetype plugin. In that case you can override it by putting `setlocal commentstring=\ #%s` in a file called `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim`. This file will get loaded by Vim after the standard filetype plugin and is IMHO the best place if you want to override the default settings -- even more so, if you want to change more than one setting.

Comment: Thanks you @JürgenKrämer again. I get it now. Yes you are right. It was set in `/usr/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin/sh.vim` and I can override it. I will keep this best practice. For `setlocal commentstring=\<tab>#%s`, I actually typed the `<tab>` literally. I found that `\t`does not work. Any better suggestion to specify `<tab>` in the setting files?

Comment: For every global option there is an identically named special variable with a leading ampersand, and for every local variable there is one with a leading `l:&`. They are aliased to the actual options. You can use these variables in "normal" assignments where you provide the option value as a number or a string. In string values the normal rules for special characters apply, so for your example you can use `let &l:commentstring="\t#%s"` to include a tab.

Comment: Yeah. Bingo. Thank you @JürgenKrämer. Now I learn a lot more. `let &l:commentstring="\t#%s"` works. `l:&` should be a typo. It should be a leading `&l:` instead.